# POST data with request module on Node.JS

Tags: node.js, request

This module is 'request https://github.com/mikeal/request

I think i'm following every step but i'm missing an argument..

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost/test2.php',
         body: "mes=heydude"
         }, function(error, response, body){
            console.log(body);
    });
```

on the other end i have

```
echo $_POST['mes'];
```

And i know the php isn't wrong...

Comment: Why not use `http.request` directly? I have a feeling the body does not map to querystring parameters like that. Try `url: 'http://localhost/test2.php?mes=heydude'`

Comment: In Node.js 18, the fetch API is available on the global scope by default

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js/71991867#71991867

Answer (score 218, accepted):

**EDIT:** You should check out [Needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle). It does this for you and supports multipart data, and a lot more.

I figured out I was missing a header

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  url:     'http://localhost/test2.php',
  body:    "mes=heydude"
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Remember to `JSON.stringify` your data if you are sending `'content-type': 'application/json'`

Answer (score 82):

When using `request` for an http POST you can add parameters this way:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  url:     'http://localhost/test2.php',
  form:    { mes: "heydude" }
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 52):

I had to post key value pairs without form and I could do it easily like below:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  url: 'http://localhost/test2.php',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {mes: 'heydude'}
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 45):

If you're posting a json body, dont use the `form` parameter. Using `form` will make the arrays into `field[0].attribute`, `field[1].attribute` etc. Instead use `body` like so.

```
var jsonDataObj = {'mes': 'hey dude', 'yo': ['im here', 'and here']};
request.post({
    url: 'https://api.site.com',
    body: jsonDataObj,
    json: true
  }, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: "jsonDataObj" must be stringified (JSON.stringify(...)) otherwise it crashes

Comment: Actually mine crashes if you stringify it.  It probably depends how the receiving server is set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I find the doc for this? Since I doubted the post method, but the doc in Github is not enough fixing this issue.

Answer (score 16):

```
var request = require('request');
request.post('http://localhost/test2.php', 
    {form:{ mes: "heydude" }}, 
    function(error, response, body){
        console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Install request module, using `npm install request`
2. In code:

   ```
   var request = require('request');
   var data = '{ "request" : "msg", "data:" {"key1":' + Var1 + ', "key2":' + Var2 + '}}';
   var json_obj = JSON.parse(data);
   request.post({
       headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
       url: 'http://localhost/PhpPage.php',
       form: json_obj
   }, function(error, response, body){
     console.log(body)
   });
   ```

Comment: Aside from the errors in the json string, this one did the trick for me!  Note that the "form" section has an object passed to it, so you could just define everything in there as an object to begin with and not do that prep work

Answer (score 4):

Adding `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` into the headers is vital to interact with an endpoint using `PHP` code.
I have to get the data from a `POST` method of the `PHP` code.  What worked for me was:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');

const link = 'http://your-website-link.com/sample.php';
let params = { 'A': 'a', 'B': 'b' };

params = querystring.stringify(params); // changing into querystring eg 'A=a&B=b'

request.post({
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, // important to interect with PHP
  url: link,
  body: params,
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I highly recommend axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios install it with npm or yarn

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('http://your_server/your_script.php')
    .then( response => {
    console.log('Respuesta', response.data);
    })
    .catch( response => {
        console.log('Error', response);
    })
    .finally( () => {
        console.log('Finalmente...');
    });
```