# Node NPM Request how to send a post request

Tags: node.js, requestjs

I have been googling for this and only found this.

```
    let req = request({
        url: "http://localhost/api/v1/phone",
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            param1: "abc",
            param2: "def"
        }
    }, function callback(error, response, body) {});
```

This doesn't work. The error is:

```
client.js:771 POST http://localhost/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)
```

How to fix this? This fails with the same eror if I change it to request.post.

```
    let req = request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/v1/phone'

    }, (error, response, body) =>{
        logger.log('test123.error', error);
        logger.log('test123.response', response);
        logger.log('test123.body', body);
    });
```

but apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST data with request module on Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432693/post-data-with-request-module-on-node-js)

Comment: Sorry. Actually I found the answer. I'm not using npm request. I'm using Superagent. That's why the syntax doens't work.