# curl command equivalent in nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, post

I have the curl command here which is working as I want:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @cats.json http://localhost:8080
```

And I would like to get help on translating this into nodejs

I currently have localhost set up and my goal is to display data stored in a JSON file. I currently copy and paste the data into postman and post the data to the localhost but I want to not use postman. The curl command was useful but I want to incorporate it into my code.

I've tried

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
  url:     'http://localhost/8080',
  body:    "someData"
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

I've tried this but it doesn't provide the same outcome as the curl command does where the data appears in my localhost

Comment: What outcome does it provide? Do you get an error?

Comment: check this thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432693/post-data-with-request-module-on-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman, you can export NodeJS request code out:

[image]

Click on Code
Then select NodeJS -> Request.
Copy to Clipboard

[image]

Comment: if my data is all in a file, how would I input that file into the body field?