# node-fetch proxy a remote file as response

Tags: node.js, pdf, node-fetch

I have a node application which needs to do the following:

1. POST a request with some HTML in the body to a PHP API that returns a PDF
2. Return the PDF directly to the browser

I am trying something like this with `node-fetch`:

```
const response = await fetch('https://php-pdf-api.test', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'html': '<div>Hello</div>'
  }),
  header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})

const data = await response.text()
res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
res.send(data)
```

Which results in a jumbled file:

[image: jumbled PDF output]

I imagine something is happening to the encoding when using `response.text()`, how can I pass this data on to the user's browser properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291305/436014

I realized I don't even need `node-fetch` and could accomplish this directly with `request` like so:

```
request.post({
  url: 'https://php-pdf-api.test',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'html': '<div>Hello</div>'
   }),
  json: true
}).pipe(res)
```

Comment: I know you solved using `request` but since it is deprecated did you manage to do the same using `fetch`?