# HTTP PUT Request with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to make an HTTP PUT request with node.js. I've tried a lot of different things, but can't get it working.

The idea is to have a method for putting the file, eg:

```
function putFile(file_path, callback) {
    // Put the file
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example which sends a `POST` request: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/http.html#http.request , basically you just have to change it to `PUT`.

You could open your file using [createReadStream()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/fs.html#fs.createReadStream) and [pipe()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/all.html#stream.pipe) it to the response object.

Here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js/6158966#6158966) which uses `readFile()`, the problem with that is that the whole file is loaded into memory, so better use `createReadStream()` and `pipe()` if the files are large.

Comment: Thanks. That's the example I was using. Adding createReadStream() and pipe() was the missing piece.