# Sending the POST request from node.js server with *.zip/*.wgt file to the Wookie Server

Tags: node.js, post, widget, zip, http-post

I try to send *.wgt file (which is valid *.zip file) with POST request from node.js to other server on which Wookie Server is runinng. I have followed node.js documentation of the *http server* and *fs* and two other posts on stackoverflow ([Node.js POST File to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943010/node-js-post-file-to-server) and [how to upload a file from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744990/how-to-upload-a-file-from-node-js)) but I did not managed this to work.

What I have already done:

I have *.wgt file which is stored on the node.js server. I create a http server in node, prepare the POST request to the Wookie REST API, get *.zip file stream with `fs.createReadStream()` and I stream it with `pipe()`. But I get the following error response:

> Error: No file found uploaded to the server. The request sent by the
>   client was syntactically incorect (No file uploaded to server).

The Wookie Server API reference for this particular request looks as follows:

> POST {wookie}/widgets {file}  -  Adds a widget to the server. The method echoes the widget metadata in the response.

My code looks as follows:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var file_name = 'test.wgt';

// auth data for access to the wookie server api
var username = 'java';
var password = 'java';
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');     

// boundary key for post request            
var boundaryKey = Math.random().toString(16);
var wookieResponse = "";

// take content length of the request body: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943010/node-js-post-file-to-server
var body_before_file = 
      '--' + boundaryKey + '\r\n'
      + 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' 
      + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file_name+'"\r\n'
      + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n';
var body_after_file = "--"+boundaryKey+"--\r\n\r\n";

fs.stat('./uploads/'+file_name, function(err, file_info) {
    console.log(Buffer.byteLength(body_before_file) +"+"+ file_info.size +"+"+ Buffer.byteLength(body_after_file));

    var content_length = Buffer.byteLength(body_before_file) + 
        file_info.size +
        Buffer.byteLength(body_after_file);

    // set content length and other values to the header
    var header = {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'Content-Length': String(content_length),
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary="--'+boundaryKey+'"',//,
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
    };
    // set request options
    var options = {
            host: appOptions.hostWP,
            port: 8080,
            path: '/wookie/widgets',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: header
    };

    // create http request
    var requ = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');    
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            wookieResponse = wookieResponse + chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function (chunk) {
            wookieResponse = wookieResponse + chunk;
            console.log(wookieResponse);
        })
    });

    // write body_before_file (see above) to the body request
    requ.write(body_before_file);

    // prepare createReadStream and pipe it to the request
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./uploads/'+file_name);
    fileStream.pipe(requ, {end: false});

    // finish request with boundaryKey
    fileStream.on('end', function() {
        requ.end('--' + boundaryKey + '--\r\n\r\n');
    });

    requ.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
});
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I achive correct *.wgt/*.zip file upload with POST request from node.js?

Cheers,
Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved the goal which were described in question: to send POST request from node.js with *.zip/*.wgt file to the other server.

I did not managed that with the aproach introduced in the question: to build request step-by-step using request module. I do some reaserch and I found intersting node.js module: [form-data](http://github.com/felixge/node-form-data). What does this modul do? Readme.md says:

> A module to create readable "multipart/form-data" streams. Can be used
>   to submit forms and file uploads to other web applications.

In part where example where listed I found following example:

```js
var CRLF = '\r\n';
var form = new FormData();

var options = {
  header: CRLF + '--' + form.getBoundary() + CRLF + 'X-Custom-Header: 123' + CRLF + CRLF,
  knownLength: 1
};

form.append('my_buffer', buffer, options);

form.submit('http://example.com/', function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Done');
});
```

In the example above there is a `FormData()` object created, data is appended to the form and then form is submited. Additionally there is a custom hedear created.

I merged the code which I presented in question with the code from above presented example and got the code which resolved my problem:

```js
var formData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');

var CRLF = '\r\n';
var form = new FormData();

var options = {
    header: '--' + form.getBoundary() +
            CRLF + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";'+  
                    'filename="bubbles.wgt"'+
            CRLF + 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' +
            CRLF + CRLF
    };

form.append('file',fs.readFileSync('./uploads/bubbles.wgt'),options);

form.submit({
        host: host,
        port: '8080',
        path: '/wookie/widgets',
        auth: 'java:java'
        }, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Done');
            console.log(res);
        });
```

I hope it will be helpful to the others.

Cheers,
Michal