# Vue Axios doesnt return response

Tags: vue.js, post, get, axios, put

I have problem with vue axios.

I am trying to send data using get / put but I can not read it on the server side.
Using POST everything works, so I do not know what the problem is.
Btw. Everything works in PostMan.

```
axios({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: `http://example.org`,
    data:  Qs.stringify(data),
}).then(response => (console.log(response.data)))
```

Comment: What happens on the server side, what's your code there?

Comment: for now only print_r ($ _ GET);

Comment: "Everything works in PostMan" means that also PUT requests work?
What does it say in the browser's "Network" tab, do you get an answer there or does the request time out?

Comment: Console : Array
(
),

Comment: Ya, Put work on PostMan

Comment: Api file status : 200

Comment: Right, so in the console there is something, just that it's an empty array?
What does the response preview show for your PUT request in the network tab?

Comment: Ya, array is empty, on POST is good, but why? Show empty array

Comment: What's the response in PostMan for the PUT request?

Comment: Array
(
    [prize_concession] => 39
    [prize_normal] => 49
    [name] => abcd
)

Comment: Sorry, but your problem is that on the server side you cannot read data when sending a PUT request from axios, correct?
If you only replace 'PUT' by 'POST' in your code above, does that work?

Comment: ya its works when i change GET to POST on axios and server side to $_POST

Comment: What happens if you change `$ _ GET` to `$ _ PUT` in your server side code?

Comment: empty answer, even not array

Comment: Yes, but does the server print out the data?

Comment: "Nothing to preview"

Comment: If everything works well in PostMan for the exact same PUT request, and also it works when you send a POST request from axios but not with a PUT request, then I've got no idea why it doesn't work, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I am using axios PUT this way and it works well..

```
axios.put("http://example.org", "plaintextbodyorstringifiedmaybe", {headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}}).then(response => (console.log(response.data)))
```

Comment: and how you get data on server side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225045/http-put-request-with-node-js

Comment: ? i still dont now what should i do

Answer (score 1):

```
Vue.axios.put("http://localhost:4000/api/" + this.$route.params.id)
    .then((res) => {
     console.log(res);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP PUT response has an empty body [HTTP PUT on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)

In case of a successful request, the response body is empty, whereas a successful POST request's response has a body [HTTP POST on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

Comment: but how i can insert data from query to mysql?