# How to set Content-Length when sending POST request in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, post, node.js, request, content-length

```
var https = require('https');  

var p = '/api/username/FA/AA?ZOHO_ACTION=EXPORT&ZOHO_OUTPUT_FORMAT=JSON&ZOHO_ERROR_FORMAT=JSON&ZOHO_API_KEY=dummy1234&ticket=dummy9876&ZOHO_API_VERSION=1.0';  

var https = require('https');  
var options = {  
  host: 'reportsapi.zoho.com',  
  port: 443,  
  path: p,  
  method: 'POST'  
};  

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);  
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);  
  res.on('data', function(d) {  
    process.stdout.write(d);  
  });  
});  
req.end();  

req.on('error', function(e) {  
  console.error(e);  
});
```

When i run the above code i am getting below error.

**error message:**

```
statusCode:  411  
headers:  { 'content-type': 'text/html',  
  'content-length': '357',  
  connection: 'close',  
  date: 'Thu, 24 Nov 2011 19:58:51 GMT',  
  server: 'ZGS',  
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=604800' }  
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  


411 - Length Required
```

How to fix the abobe error?
I have tried doing below

```
var qs =   'ZOHO_ACTION=EXPORT&ZOHO_OUTPUT_FORMAT=JSON&ZOHO_ERROR_FORMAT=JSON&ZOHO_API_KEY=dummy1234&ticket=dummy9876&ZOHO_API_VERSION=1.0';
'   
options.headers = {'Content-Length': qs.length}
```

But if I try this way I am getting below error:

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],  
  arguments: undefined,  
  type: undefined,  
  message: 'socket hang up' }
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks
koti

PS:If I enter the whole url into browser address bar and hit enter I am getting JSON response as expected.

Comment: please do not use data.length, I bumped to this issue and author said do not use data.length, instead, use Buffer.byteLength(data). Ref question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692580/node-js-post-causes-error-socket-hang-up-code-econnreset and ref issue: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1749

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that the solution to the given problem, when you *do* want to make a POST request, is apparently to set the "headers" field of the options object to contain a 'Content-Length' field.

See code here:

[How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js)

Comment: But how do you find out the right value to put on the content-length field? I have a json response, and I'm getting an `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` error. Wonder how I can set it to the right value to stop getting this error.

Comment: @UlyssesAlves you should just be able to set it to the length of the string representing the JSON. Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 5):

i think you're missing two things.
Assuming **p** is both your **endpoint** and your **url-encoded payload**.

You could split your p variable into the both api path, and the post_data payload you need to write before ending the request.

```
var p = 'ZOHO_ACTION=EXPORT&ZOHO_OUTPUT_FORMAT=JSON&ZOHO_ERROR_FORMAT=JSON&ZOHO_API_KEY=dummy1234&ticket=dummy9876&ZOHO_API_VERSION=1.0';

var https = require('https');  
var options = {  
  host: 'reportsapi.zoho.com',  
  port: 443,  
  path: '/api/username/FA/AA',  
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(p)
  } 
}
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);  
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);  
  res.on('data', function(d) {  
    process.stdout.write(d);  
  });  
});
req.write(p);  
req.end();
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function(req, res) {

    req.on('data',function(data){

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain','Content-Length':data.toString().length+''});
        res.write(data.toString());
        res.end();
    });  

});
```

Comment: length is suppose to be in bytes not number of characters

Answer (score -6):

I am able to solve this problem by changing the method from POST to GET

Thanks
koti

Comment: are you still facing this issue? Is it fixed? Which version of node you are using? I'm facing the same issue. Its looking like issue with node. Have you found anything?

Comment: Your question was about POST requests, so changing to GET requests is not an answer.