# Send file with form-data and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, form-data

I am trying to send a video to a videosite, I am able to upload the video using the REST api and postman, so I know the api works as intended. Now I want to do exatcly the same request using axios. I have code that looks like the example on how to use form-data and axios:

```js
const form = new FormData();
const stream = fs.createReadStream(PATH_TO_FILE);

form.append('image', stream);

// In Node.js environment you need to set boundary in the header field 'Content-Type' by calling method `getHeaders`
const formHeaders = form.getHeaders();

axios.post('http://example.com', form, {
  headers: {
    ...formHeaders,
  },
})
.then(response => response)
.catch(error => error)
```

I get the error that `data: 'Content-Length is required'`

Any ideas?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9641742/8945943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to set Content-Length accordingly:

`"Content-Length": fs.statSync(filePath)['size']`

Answer (score 2):

May be I got your questions wrong , you want to add Content-Length in the header.
I can see you are uploading video stream. So first you have to calculate the data chunk length.

('Content-Length', File.getSize(stream))
Reference: [Can I stream a file upload to S3 without a content-length header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header)

You can make the post request as multi-part type :   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'.
It is preferable way to send large data to server.
You can check this link : [How do I set multipart in axios with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react)

If I got your question wrong , plese comment or reply . Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Your comment helped me find the solution! See below for the solution:

`Content-Length": fs.statSync(filePath)['size']`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is to actually use the FormData's own method:

```
const headers = { 'content-length': formData.getLengthSync(), ...formData.getHeaders() }
```

This will be more accurate because it includes any other data you may add.

To expound, if you are using a ReadStream, you must use the async function instead.

```
const { promisify } = require('util')

const getLength = promisify(formData.getLength.bind(formData))
const contentLength = await getLength()
const headers = { 'content-length': contentLength, ...formData.getHeaders() }
```