# Getting a 400 when using http client.request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postdata

I'm trying to fetch some data from a server using nodejs. I would like to send a `POST` data. There are two things that I would like to know about.

1. How do I send the POST data?
2. Whatever request I make using GET or POST, I always get a 400-BadRequest error. Have been searching through to solve this the whole day. Was not able to solve.

I'm sending the POST data now like `request.write(JSON.stringify({key:"value"}));` .. for which I'm always getting a 400 to whatever site I try this. Even on apache running at `127.0.0.1` on a php file that accepts the POST data.

Comment: It's not unclear from your question who is sending a POST and who is receiving it? Are you posting a form to node.js and you want node to reply with content? Or are you trying to get node.js to post to another server? Also, please post your app.js or equivalent code.

Comment: Im trying to get nodejs to post to another server. (mentioned that im using http client.request in nodejs)

Comment: Client.request just outputs to the page being rendered by node.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BrYgF/ . The code that sends the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in another SO thread: [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js)

Essentially:

use `require('http');`

set `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` in the options

In the callback, use `res.on('data', ...)` to transfer the posted info.