# Sending data through POST request from a node.js server to a node.js server

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send data through a `POST` request from a node.js server to another node.js server. What I do in the "client" node.js is the following:

```
var options = {
    host: 'my.url',
    port: 80,
    path: '/login',
    method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('status: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

This chunk is taken more or less from the node.js website so it should be correct. The only thing I don't see is how to include username and password in the `options` variable to actually login. This is how I deal with the data in the server node.js (I use express):

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var user = {};
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
        ...
});
```

How can I add those `username` and `password` fields to the `options` variable to have it logged in?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP POST request in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Posting data is a matter of sending a query string (just like the way you would send it with an URL after the `?`) as the request body.

This requires `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers, so the receiving server knows how to interpret the incoming data. <sup>(*)</sup>

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var data = querystring.stringify({
      username: yourUsernameValue,
      password: yourPasswordValue
    });

var options = {
    host: 'my.url',
    port: 80,
    path: '/login',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Sending data requires the Content-Type header to be set correctly, i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the traditional format that a standard  HTML form would use.

It's easy to send JSON (`application/json`) in exactly the same manner; just `JSON.stringify()` the data beforehand.

URL-encoded data supports one level of structure (i.e. key and value). JSON is useful when it comes to exchanging data that has a nested structure.

The bottom line is: The server must be able to interpret the content type in question. It could be `text/plain` or anything else; there is no need to convert data if the receiving server understands it as it is.

Add a charset parameter (e.g. `application/json; charset=Windows-1252`) if your data is in an unusual character set, i.e. not UTF-8. This can be necessary if you read it from a file, for example.

Comment: Great answer about 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', I was searching all over, thanks!

Comment: Proper explanation with perfect coding.

Comment: On the part when you post the data, assuming it is `req.write(data);` that does this action, In the terminal that outputs the response data from the server, how would one collect that in a variable for instance?

Answer (score 23):

You can also use [Requestify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify), a really cool and very simple HTTP client I wrote for nodeJS + it supports caching.

Just do the following for executing a POST request:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

requestify.post('http://example.com', {
    hello: 'world'
})
.then(function(response) {
    // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
    response.getBody();
});
```

Comment: installing requestify fails. node-gyp rebuild not ok : code 0

Comment: @marcel: It worked fine for me as well, you need to look into build essentials for that `requestify` package and install them first.

Comment: Thanks guys! The next version that will be out soon won't need python anymore since jQuery (that is currently used for parsing XML responses it going out of the core as a optional dependency (-:

Comment: Can this be used to mimic a form-post?

Comment: I've tried it, I have problems with the body segment of my POST requests

Comment: How to send data in requestify? Shall i send JSON data in body:{} ?