# NodeJS: how to perform Ajax Post with FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, post

I am testing a local HTML Form sending data to an aspx application as backend. Since I have some problem with CORS (even on localhost) I am trying to emulate the Ajax request performed by jQuery with NodeJS. I don't know if this is the right way to do. In the HTML form, after the jQuery validation, this is what I do:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }            
    });
    //console.log($(form).serialize())
}
```

and it works, until CORS ends the request. I mean that I can retrieve the data from the backend application.
Instead, if I do:

```
function loadDoc() {    

  var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  /*var FormData = require('form-data');
  var myform = new FormData();
  myform.append('firstname', 'foo');*/

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
   }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:1308/ImperoOrdini/ImperoOrdini.aspx?CMD=NUOVOORDINE", true);

  //which is the same string I get from .serialize() in jQuery
  xhttp.send("firstname=foo&email=some@domain.it");
}

loadDoc();
```

I cannot get anything from the server application. If I want to get the parameter `firstname` from the POST data, I get `null`. So, where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768192/sending-data-through-post-request-from-a-node-js-server-to-a-node-js-server) is the only workaround I have found useful  in NodeJS:

```
var http = require('http');

var querystring = require('querystring');
var post_data = querystring.stringify({'firstname':'Lory'});

var post_options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '1308',
  path: '/ImperoOrdini/ImperoOrdini.aspx?CMD=NUOVOORDINE',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
  }
};

// Set up the request
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
  });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```

I had also tried with:

```
var request = require('ajax-request');
request.post({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1308/ImperoOrdini/ImperoOrdini.aspx?CMD=NUOVOORDINE',
  data: {'firstname':'Lory'},
  headers: {}
  }, function(err, res, body) {
     console.log(res);
   }
);
```

but it did not work too. I feel such an ignorant and I would like to know the differences between those 3 libraries. 
I have some doubts concerning the fact I must use `querystring.stringify()` in the working solution, because POST data are not in the URL and should not be uder the limits of query string, if I remember well.

Comment: do you specifically want to get it working with vanilla Node? (libraries make this cleaner). The Node API is not the same as the browser one.

Comment: No, I don't have any specific need. As I've said I don't know NodeJS unfortunately. I just wanted to send a standard Ajax Post Request with some data to my server. Is it possible?

Comment: As per my understanding, you are trying to post data from nodejs to aspx am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: Can you share your aspx piece of code too

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have an aspx code. The backend application is built with a framework (Instand Developer) where I write pseudo cose which is compiled into a DLL executable. So all my code, events and interface methods I implement in the IDE are not real code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest [request](https://github.com/request/request#forms) module. while doing ajax call post, we can post the data by form or JSON format. It's based on receiver end point how they are receiving.

I hope you are trying to post form data.

```
 var request = require('request');
 request.post({
    url:'http://service.com/upload', 
    form: {'firstname':'Lory'}
  }, function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
     /* ... */ 
  })
```

If you are trying to do normal JSON post.

```
var request = require('request')
request({
     method: 'POST',
     uri: 'http://www.google.com',
     body:{'firstname':'Lory'}
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
     /* ... */ 
})
```

[request](https://github.com/request/request#forms) module provide lots of options. Play with that then you will get the better idea.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. As I had updated my post, I had already tried to use the request module but the result is the same...there's no key with a value ad the backend application.

Comment: I want to know how end point (aspx) is receiving the data then only I will know how to pass value from nodejs.

Comment: Whether aspx is expecting querystring params?

Comment: I'm not sure because the code generated is not mine and I can't know how it works as this that framework is not open source and it generates itself the server application. Anyway I suppose, yes, it might expect querystring parameters because they told me the only way to send a request to that application is to append that `CMD=NUOVOORDINE` to the end of the application URL. Then, I implemented an event which should get the data from the request using some given API. But I don't know anything about the implementation. Anyway don't get mad for this. I know there are many limits...

Comment: Okay fine. They have a lot of option, try one by one if you don't know about receiver point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903476/node-js-http-get-request-with-query-string-parameters try this too.

Comment: Thank you, it was very kind of yours. If you want, just explain me a thing: if it is strictly asked to pass params by query string, wouldn't this nullify the advantages of a POST request, which is not supposed to have params in the URL? I hope I'm not saying rubbish, I'm just a junior developer...

Comment: I will suggest if its get call go querystring, if it's post call then go for body

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
    <head>

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>     
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
                            <div>
                              <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                              <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                            </div>
                           <div>
                              <label for="rating">Comment:</label>
                              <textarea id="rating" name="comment"></textarea>
                            </div>

                          <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
         </form>

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
           $('form').submit(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                  //collect the form data using Id Selector what ever data you need to send to server
                        let comment=$('#comment').val();
                        let rating= $('#rating').val()

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'replace your url',
                            data: JSON.stringify({"comment": comment, "rating": rating }),
                            processData: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });


                    });
                })


    </script>
    </html>
```