# Sending POST data to a page with a GET parameter with Nodejs

Tags: forms, node.js, post, get

I'm trying to send POST data to a test.php file, which handles POST data only if it was provided a specific GET data. Unfortunately I have no clue how to do that; and have been searching for about an hour.

Any help would be appreciated, as i'm currently playing around a lot with this amazing stuff.

Thanks in advance;

Some clarification:

Say you have a index.php looking like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['p']))
    echo count($_POST) . ' -- ' . count($_GET);
else echo 'fuuu';

?>
<form action="?p" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="lolw" value="Go" />
</form>
```

If you submit that form, PHP's `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals will both contain 1 element.

Now, lets try to run that form through nodeJS.

Here is my test case (which is merely some cutpasting from the doku):

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
   hostname: 'localhost',
   port: 80,
   path: '/test.php?lolw=1&p',
   method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  }).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('error in chunk');
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.toString());
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

CLI output gives for the body:
0 -- 2 and then follows the form.

My point is: is it possible to send *some* parameters through GET and some others through POST, and specifying which needs to be sent through GET and which through POST ?

Comment: Makes no sense. Please clarify your question or post code

Comment: The above makes no sense at all. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Edited for the sake of clarity, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an HTTP request in node.js, you'll need to use [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). You can set the method to "POST" and still have get parameters in your URL. You'll need to set the *Content-Length* header to the length of your data and the *Content-Type* header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for a "standard" POST request.

Your question is pretty vague. If you're having problems with something in particular, just show your code and ask the more precise question.

Comment: Thank you, that drove me to the answer! Just have to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js.