# loading the php file on node

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Hi I'm trying to develop a chat system using socket.io, express.io and node.js everything is going smoothly, and I have been following the documentation from them.

The problem is as soon as I'm trying to integrate the design to the skeleton app that I have developed, it wont load correctly. It only gives me a popup notifying me to either download or open the PHP file.

here is my index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('message.php');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have tried searching for it and no good I cant seem to find a solution...

Comment: how are you handling this client side ? and you really should consider the use of an express template engine like ejs or node...

Comment: I think it does exactly what you have told it with your code. What you have done is sending a PHP file to the client. What are you trying to do? Do you want the PHP file to execute and send the result of _that_ execution to client?

Comment: @Krumia Yes I need to execute the php file because the whole interface is there... if i put instead message.html instead of message.php it will work..

Comment: @kastormania this are running under node.. sorry but what exactly do you mean?

Comment: yeah of course it's running under nodejs, your server is doing exactly what you're asking it to do : sending a php file back to the client, but nodejs server won't execute your php code. with nodejs and express you can use an engine template like [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html) to render your "design"

Comment: @kastormania but its still on html format i believe? ejs is the same as jade?

Comment: ejs and jade are both template engines, but each one has its own syntax

Comment: I see so how can node interpret my php file? sorry if I'm asking stupid questions because I'm new to websocket and node so basically my knowledge here is so little

Comment: you cand use the [php-node](https://www.npmjs.org/package/php-node) package to execute your php code

Comment: ok I'll research that thanks for the input @kastormania

Answer (score 2):

`socket.io sendfile` will just send the contents of the file to the client. It does not matter if you give a PHP script or an image file to `sendfile`. It does the same.

If you want to execute a PHP script, you can do one of the following:

- Run a separate web server that interprets PHP, and then connect to that server from Node.js, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027849/1461424).
- Run the PHP interpreter with [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), then send the standard output of that process to client.