# Node.js send post request with data?

Tags: node.js, nginx

How can i send the following request in a Node.js environment?

```
curl -s -v -X POST 'http://localhost/pub?id=my_channel_1' -d 'Hello World!'
```

Im trying to build a Node.js server together with the Nginx Push Stream Module.

Comment: Send from the server or to the server?

Comment: I want to send from Node.js to Nginx, so i want the above to be executed on my Node.js server

Comment: Perhaps this will help you out? http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: I dont understand where to set my id and data in that example

Comment: Allright, fair enough :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js

Comment: Saw that post but i still dont understand where to input ID and Data :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24302/discussion-between-limelights-and-alosyius)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the 'request' module, I am using it and I feel very comfortable with it.

Comment: silviu, cum pot lua legatura cu tine. in legatura cu node.js :)

Comment: n-am acces la el pe linkedid. Iar aici nu il vad. Ms

Answer (score 1):

to expand on @Silviu Burcea 's recommendation of the request module:

```
//Set up http server:
function handler(req,res){ 
  console.log(req.method+'@ '+req.url);
  res.writeHead(200); res.end();
};
require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3333);

// Send post request to http server
// curl -s -v -X POST 'http://localhost/pub?id=my_channel_1' -d 'Hello World!'
// npm install request (https://github.com/mikeal/request)
var request = require('request'); 
request(
{ uri:'http://localhost:3333/pub?id=my_channel_1',
  method:'POST',
  body:'Hello World!',
},
function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { console.log('Success') }
});
```