# Foursquare Check-in Reply

Tags: node.js, express, foursquare

I am trying to Connect my application to foursquare and I want to display a message when a user checks in to certain places. I am trying to use their real time api https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

Everything works fine until the very end, ( when I have to send a reply post request https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/reply) I am using express and node.js. Here is what my post request looks like.

```
app.post('/handlepush', function(req, res) {
 var checkin_id =req.param('checkin');
 console.log(checkin_id);
 var obj = JSON.parse(checkin_id);
 var id = obj.id;

res.end('It worked!');

var token = "********************************";

var post_data = querystring.stringify({text : "awesome"});
var options = {
    host: 'api.foursquare.com',
    path: '/v2/checkins/' + id + '/reply?oauth_token=' + token,
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST'
};

var req2 = https.request(options, function(res2) {
    res2.setEncoding('utf8');
    res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });

req2.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

});
req2.write(post_data);
req2.end();



});
```

this is the error I get, for some reason I am not able to add parameters for my post:
    BODY: {"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"Must provide parameter       text"},"response":{}}

Comment: can anyone provide a sample API call if there is a problem with mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually send your request. See: [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js)

```
var req2 = http.request(options, function(res2) {
    res2.setEncoding('utf8');
    res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});
req2.end();
```

Comment: so I changed a bit, its almost working now.. but I just need to figure out a way to add the parameters.

Comment: "text" should be a parameter in your query string:
`path: '/v2/checkins/' + id + '/reply?oauth_token=' + token + '&text=Text%20to%20show%20user,`

Comment: yea that works! but I am confused a little bit I thought post parameters shouldnt be in the url.. ?