# How to write data to a JSON file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

For example, I have a `.JSON` file that has the following:

```
[{"honda": "accord", "color": "red"},{"ford": "focus", "color": "black"}]
```

What would be the javascript code to push another object `{"nissan": "sentra", "color": "green"}` into this `.json` array to make the `.json` file look like

```
[{"honda": "accord", "color": "red"},{"ford": "focus", "color": "black"},{"nissan": "sentra", "color": "green"}]
```

The reason I'm asking is I am finding a lot of information online on how to pull data from a .json file using AJAX but not writing new data to the .json file using AJAX to update the .json file with additional data.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The solution to this depends on what sort of server you're using. It will most likely involve sending an authenticated POST request to a server-side script.

Comment: You have to get the data, parse it, mutate it, serialize it, send it back to the server and persist it. Which part are you having problems with? Note that the persisting part (writing to the file) has nothing to do with JavaScript. That is all handled by the server. Which server side language are you using?

Comment: I assume your file is part of some server deployed web app and you use AJAX to transport the contents to a browser and then capture new information there and want to send an AJAX request to some update  method on the server with the new information, which lets the webapp update the file there.

Comment: If you want to know how to write a file with node, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js).  If you want to know how to add an element to an array in javascript, that is pretty basic and you could find the information easily in any tutorial page on javascript.  If it's the latter you could rephrase your question, which really has nothing to do with JSON, which is just a way to represent javascript objects as strings.  If it's about file i/o or something else it could also be worded better.  I just can't tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to be clear on what you mean by "JSON".

Some people use the term JSON incorrectly to refer to a plain old JavaScript object, such as `[{a: 1}]`. This one happens to be an array. If you want to add a new element to the array, just `push` it, as in

```
var arr = [{a: 1}];
arr.push({b: 2});

< [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
```

The word JSON may also be used to refer to a string which is encoded in JSON format:

```
var json = '[{"a": 1}]';
```

Note the (single) quotation marks indicating that this is a string. If you have such a string that you obtained from somewhere, you need to first parse it into a JavaScript object, using `JSON.parse`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Now you can manipulate the object any way you want, including `push` as shown above. If you then want to put it back into a JSON string, then you use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var new_json = JSON.stringify(obj.push({b: 2}));
'[{"a": 1}, {"b": 1}]'
```

JSON is also used as a common way to format data for transmission of data to and from a server, where it can be saved (persisted). This is where ajax comes in. Ajax is used both to obtain data, often in JSON format, from a server, and/or to send data in JSON format up to to the server. If you received a response from an ajax request which is JSON format, you may need to `JSON.parse` it as described above. Then you can manipulate the object, put it back into JSON format with `JSON.stringify`, and use another ajax call to send the data to the server for storage or other manipulation.

You use the term "JSON file". Normally, the word "file" is used to refer to a physical file on some device (**not** a string you are dealing with in your code, or a JavaScript object). The browser has no access to physical files on your machine. It cannot read or write them. Actually, the browser does not even really have the notion of a "file". Thus, you cannot just read or write some JSON file on your local machine. If you are sending JSON to and from a server, then of course, the server might be storing the JSON as a file, but more likely the server would be constructing the JSON based on some ajax request, based on data it retrieves from a database, or decoding the JSON in some ajax request, and then storing the relevant data back into its database.

Do you really have a "JSON file", and if so, where does it exist and where did you get it from? Do you have a JSON-format string, that you need to parse, mainpulate, and turn back into a new JSON-format string? Do you need to get JSON from the server, and modify it and then send it back to the server? Or is your "JSON file" actually just a JavaScript object, that you simply need to manipulate with normal JavaScript logic?

Answer (score 24):

JSON can be written into local storage using the JSON.stringify to serialize a JS object. You cannot write to a JSON file using only JS. Only cookies or local storage

```
    var obj = {"nissan": "sentra", "color": "green"};

localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And to retrieve the object later

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStorage'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatelly, today (September 2018) you can not find cross-browser solution for client side file writing.

> **For example:** in some browser like a Chrome we have **today** this possibility and we can write with **[FileSystemFileEntry.createWriter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry/createWriter)** with client side call, but according to the docu:
>
> *This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.*
>
> ---
>
> For IE (but not MS Edge) we could use ActiveX too, but this is only for this client.

**If you want update your JSON file cross-browser you have to use server and client side together.**

### The client side script

On client side you can make a request to the server and then you have to read the response from server. Or you could read a file with **[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)** too. For the cross-browser writing to the file you have to have some server (see below on server part).

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    jsonArr,
    method = "GET",
    jsonRequestURL = "SOME_PATH/jsonFile/";

xhr.open(method, jsonRequestURL, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        // we convert your JSON into JavaScript object
        jsonArr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        // we add new value:
        jsonArr.push({"nissan": "sentra", "color": "green"});

        // we send with new request the updated JSON file to the server:
        xhr.open("POST", jsonRequestURL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // if you want to handle the POST response write (in this case you do not need it):
        // xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ /* handle POST response */ };
        xhr.send("jsonTxt="+JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
        // but on this place you have to have a server for write updated JSON to the file
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

### Server side scripts

You can use a lot of different servers, but I would like to write about PHP and Node.js servers.

By using searching machine you could find "[free PHP Web Hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20PHP%20Web%20Hosting)*" or "[free Node.js Web Hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20Node.js%20Web%20Hosting)". For PHP server I would recommend [000webhost.com](https://www.000webhost.com/free-hosting) and for Node.js I would recommend to see and to read [this list](https://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/where-to-find-free-node-js-hosting/).

**PHP server side script solution**

The PHP script for reading and writing from JSON file:

```php
<?php

// This PHP script must be in "SOME_PATH/jsonFile/index.php"

$file = 'jsonFile.txt';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
// or if(!empty($_POST))
{
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST["jsonTxt"]);
    //may be some error handeling if you want
}
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')
// or else if(!empty($_GET))
{
    echo file_get_contents($file);
    //may be some error handeling if you want
}
?>
```

---

**Node.js server side script solution**

I think that Node.js is a little bit complex for beginner. This is not normal JavaScript like in browser. Before you start with Node.js I would recommend to read one from two books:

- [Learning Node: Moving to the Server-Side](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491943122)
- [Node.js Web Development: Server-side development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788626850)

The Node.js script for reading and writing from JSON file:

```js
var http = require("http"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    port = 8080,
    pathToJSONFile = '/SOME_PATH/jsonFile.txt';

http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    if(request.method == 'GET')
    {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        response.write(fs.readFile(pathToJSONFile, 'utf8'));
        response.end();
    }
    else if(request.method == 'POST')
    {
        var body = [];

        request.on('data', function(chunk)
        {
            body.push(chunk);
        });

        request.on('end', function()
        {
            body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            var myJSONdata = body.split("=")[1];
            fs.writeFileSync(pathToJSONFile, myJSONdata); //default: 'utf8'
        });
    }
}).listen(port);
```

**Related links for Node.js:**

- [How to Develop Web Application using pure Node.js (HTTP GET and POST, HTTP Server)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuw48-u3Yrg) (detailed video tutorial)
- [Anatomy of an HTTP Transaction](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/)
- [How to handle POST request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15427220/)
- [How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295782/)

Comment: while saving using clientside script, i am getting method not allowed (405) error, any idea on this?

Comment: @ShekharPatel, 405 errors can be traced to configuration of the Web server and security governing access to the content of the Web site. It seems that the server to which you are sending the Post request(your Site's server) has been configured to block Post request. You can configure your server to allow the Post request. For more details, go to http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html