# How do I update the data saved in a JSON file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How do I update the data saved in a JSON file using JavaScript?

for example: If i have a JSON file called 'person.json', looking like:

```
{
  "Person": [
    {
      "Firstname": "John",
      "Lastname": "Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I would like to append as new data set the name 'John Smith'.
How could I do this using JavaScript?

EDIT:
Now I tried to use 'fs.readFile()' to read my JSON file.
The application I develop is a hybrid app using cordova.
If i use 'fs.readFile()' i get the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined'.
I tried to fix this problem by adding the line 'var fs = Npm.require('fs');'.
But this causes also an error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Npm is not defined'

Is this error caused because npm is not available on a smartphone?
And how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write data to a JSON file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546100/how-to-write-data-to-a-json-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you trying to do it server side, am I right? If it's a browser app, you'll need a back-end that handles the JSON file, and then call it from your javascript running in the browser. The good news is that you can do the back-end using javascript to, see [node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `JSON.parse(data)` to parse the JSON string into an object.
Then when you're done, use `JSON.stringify(object)` to convert it into a JSON string.

You can write and read files with `fs` [link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: How can I do this without using Node.js because I am doing my backend with the Python Django?