# Creating a Javascript file of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, frontend

I would like to create a Javascript file of JSON objects. I have a front-end application, which will take no more than 600 requested JSON objects from an API, and will perform a visualization on them based on some characteristics.

I am able to load in all the JSON objects into a list of JSN objects, but that is not what I had in mind.

Ideally, I would like to be able to load them all into a .txt or .js file, where, if someone wanted to, could look into this file and see all the JSON objects. Additionally, I could directly perform manipulations on this data.

I would like to stay away from using any database for this since the records, memory, and manipulations I'm performing do not warrant it.

Is there a specific subroutine or library that can assist me with this? I apologize if this question seems naive, I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: Trying to understand the question, you have a service that you request from your front end for around 600 calls, and you would like to get a plain file, from that big json.

Comment: Store them in a `.json` file and load them using AJAX.

Comment: You 'load in all the JSON objects into a list of JSN objects'?

Comment: This could be a possible duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: duplicate of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546100/how-to-write-data-to-a-json-file-using-javascript