# Is it possible to write a JSON file using front end JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am learning Javascript and working at frontend only. I want to write a JSON file using javascript and read it. I know how to read it but don't know how to write it with frontend javascript.

Comment: Hey, just google it. found good link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546100/how-to-write-data-to-a-json-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge writing to the file system is against front-end development.
I suggest two options:

1. use cookie/localstorage
2. download the file

I would go about the first option