# How to make a welcome message then storing it to json or database

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So I was wondering how to make a welcome command.
When using /welcome (text you want to display on users join). I want to store that text in json or database so every guild would have their welcome message.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To be able to properly answer your question, please consider adding more details and especially what you've tried and what your code looks so far.

Comment: use quick.db not json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can compose your message like that in json :

```
"guild"{
  "000000000000000001": //guild id here   
    {
      "content": "your message here"
    },
  "000000000000000001":
    {
      "embeds": [
        {
          "title": "an embed",
          "description": "with description"
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

after that in your bot code you can do that

```js
const welcomeMessage = require('myjson');
```

and when you need to display your welcome message you juste need to acces at your json like that

```js
chanToSend.send(welcomeMessage.myserveurid);
```

for json editing thing I send you into this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546100/how-to-write-data-to-a-json-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for helping me <3