# Transfer variable value from a js file to a chrome snippet and snippet back to js file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, code-snippets

Basically I am trying to create a web page that will open boost mobiles web site and pull IMEI's from an MS sql database (no issues with the DB). What I can't figure out is how (or if it is even possible) to transfer variable values from a chrome snippet to my imei.js file. They are all stored in the same folder so the path should not be an issue. Can you transfer values this way and if so how?

Have tried import/export and also using src tags in my html file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link explaining how to use snippets with Chrome Dev Tools [Run snippets of JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets/)

There's different ways of creating and saving files in JavaScript. Are you using NodeJS?
You might also be able to store data in JSON files using vanilla JavaScript. There's some examples in this post [How to write data to a JSON file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32546100/1187650) I think you probably need to use a server-side script for the purpose.