# Node.js Request timeout when post to Heroku

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, heroku

After sending a POST request from my iOS app, I get the below error. The error doesn't seem to have any effect and everything continues to run fine, but I would like to know how to remove the error (as I worry there is something not entirely right which might have negative effects later)? I am wondering it there is some way to close off the POST request and avoid the error.

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/test" host=my-server.herokuapp.com request_id=fea9cffc-5e67-4301-baaa-d2fd18cfd0ea fwd="95.147.171.193" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

PS: The current iOS code I use is simply

```
@IBAction func Test(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://my-server.herokuapp.com/test")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // TODO: Handle errors
        }.resume()

}
```

even though I have also tried other versions (especially with more information in the body, which doesn't change anything).

On Heroku, I simply run

```
app.post("/test", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Test Log")
}
```

which already creates the described error.

It seems I always get the same error with the POST request, there does not seem to be a problem with GET requests.

Comment: what SLA are u on at heroku? pay attention to H12 on heroku. Read about how the timer ( 30 sec default or something ) is implemented between their front-end routers and your dynos and your workers. if you are on their FREE tier, i would want to make very sure that nothing other than their cycles of the dynos ( quiesce/ reawake ) is cause of a 30 sec. latency.

Answer (score 0):

*Please post your code, I cannot comment this as I have low reputaion.*

Request timeouts are due to the server not responding.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427220/how-to-handle-post-request-in-node-js), and see if you have set up the server properly.

If the error persists, try using a get request instead.