# GET/POST function in Node.js

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, methods, server-side

I don't how send data to server using html `<form>`..

```
<input type="text"/>
<input type="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
```

and now i want operating on sending information on server side (node.js)

in **PHP**, i will use method get/post but I'm looking for equivalent it in node.js, which module i must use?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: ... or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/

Comment: btw, no matter if you use node.js, php, ruby, perl, etc. you'll use methods get/post

Comment: i still not understand... how can i exaclty do it? :/ all this examples don't work...

Comment: how to easily gain access as php $GET_['logn'] ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make GET or POST requests to node.js, in fact your browser sends a GET request in order to retrieve any HTML whatsoever..
I'm surprised that you have been able to deliver any given that you do not seem to grasp the concept of a GET request.

You can post data to node just the same as you would with a form in a PHP application.
You must then do something with that data in your Node and deliver the appropriate response back to the browser.
You could also use AJAX to send data back and forth to node 'in the background' that is, without the browser navigating to a new page. 
I suggest you do some reading. At least learn about the HTTP protocol before asking questions that really demonstrate your lack of basic understanding of the technologies you have mentioned.
[HTTP Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: Prepare to be [more surprised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41660/34397).