# Sending HTTP POST data in NodeJS http

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send a POST request.  This is not using a web form, raw it should look like this.

```
POST /echo HTTP/1.1
Host: dpsw.info
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

One
Two
```

Using NodeJS http, this script..

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'dpsw.info',
  port: 80,
  path: '/echo',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = require('http').request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('One\nTwo');
req.end();
```

However when viewing in a sniffer, the data looks like this..

```
POST /echo HTTP/1.1
Host: dpsw.info
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

7
One
Two
0
```

I use the Request module sometimes as well, but didn't see an easy way to put in the raw data in that - only form:{}

Comment: possible duplicate of [outbound HTTP POST request in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/outbound-http-post-request-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

> Sending a 'Content-length' header will disable the default chunked encoding.

Since you don't want the [chunked transfer encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1) apparently, because that is where those additional numbers come from, you'll have to set `Content-length` yourself. However, many (most) servers will understand a chunked transfer encoding just fine.