# Does a success response header without response body cause an error in an AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, httpresponse

### Using AJAX to check for server connectivity

---

I'm trying to use a simple client AJAX post to check that the server is up before proceeding to functionality. I don't want to send any data, so I've attempted to respond to the client with a success header and leave out the body, but this is causing the client to trigger the error handler, even when the server responds.

---

Here's the server-side  snippet that handles posts to "check" from within my listener:

```
app.post('/check', function (req, res) {

        console.log("Client checking for service...");

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost',
            'Content-Length': 0,
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end();
        console.log("Client checked in!");

    });
```

---

Here's the AJAX request:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/check",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '',
    dataType: "json",

    error: function () {
        alert("Could not connect to the server! Returning to login screen.");
        signOut();
    },
    success: function () {

        DoStuff();

    }
});
```

---

*Does sending a successful response header without a response body cause an error in an AJAX request?*

Comment: Not tried `js` at server-side. Please illuminate. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't used Node yet? - *pulls man from dark cave* - Here: http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js , I give you ... ***Fire***. ----- @guest271314

Comment: Thanks ! Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js . Part issue with `$.ajax()` pieces may be that `data:type` at `ajax()` set to `json`, yet may not be `json` returned ? Only `header`, or `textStatus`, not `json` ? Also, `textStatus` not `parameter` within `success(data, textStatus, jqxhr)`, `error(data, textStatus, jqxhr)`  callbacks ? Is `res.writeHead` `json` format ?

Comment: Your code is far clearer than your English. Maybe if you were to speak to me in pure code, we would understand each other better. With that concoction there though, I'll admit I'm quite confused. @guest271314

Comment: Ok in minute, two. Thanks !

Comment: @guest271314 I do appreciate your effort though. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note Not tried `node.js`, `node.js` pieces not addressed

Edit

See at original post

server-side (`response`)

```
 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
```

js (`request`)

```
dataType: "json"
```

possibly trigger `error` handler ?

Note

At `server-side` `response`, `Content-Type` appear set to `text/plain` , `$.ajax()` `settings` for expect `json` (`application/json`) response ? Perhaps why `error` callback called each instance ? If could a) set expected response to `text/plain`, b) chain `callback` within `error()` or `fail()` callback, which get called when `content-type` not `json` returned, c) change `server-side`Content-Type setting (i.e.g., to `json`), generate and substitute `application/json` response for `text/plain` ?

Try this (pattern)

html

```
<p id="results"></p>
<button>localpost</button>
```

js (updated)

```
$(function() {

var localpost = function() {    

var callback = function(name) {
                 $("#results").html(name)
               }; 

var request = $.ajax({
    url : "/echo/json/",
    type:"POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { json : [] },
    statusCode : {
    200: function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            if (textStatus === "success" 
               && jqxhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") === (0 || null)) {
               alert(textStatus
               +"\nCould not connect to the server! Returning to login screen.");

               callback("textStatus: "
               + textStatus+"<br />jqxhr status: " +j qxhr.state()
               + "<br />content-length : " 
               + jqxhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")
               + "<br />status : "+jqxhr.status);
       // signOut();
            };

    }
  }
});
        // `success` callback
request.then(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    if (textStatus === "success") {
        // DoStuff()
       console.log(textStatus);
    };  
},
        // `error` callback
  function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (textStatus != "success") {
        // DoStuff()
       console.log(errorThrown);
    };  
})
};

    $("button").on("click", localpost);
    // localpost()    

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/Cer4G/