# Making a REST call in Node.js that requires client certificate for authentication

Tags: node.js, rest, certificate

Is there a way to make a rest call that requires a client certificate for authentication through Node.js ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do that quite simply, here done using a regular https request;

```
var https = require('https'),                  // Module for https
    fs =    require('fs');                     // Required to read certs and keys

var options = {
    key:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/client.key'),  // Secret client key
    cert:  fs.readFileSync('ssl/client.crt'),  // Public client key
    // rejectUnauthorized: false,              // Used for self signed server
    host: "rest.localhost",                    // Server hostname
    port: 8443                                 // Server port
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';    
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

https.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: How do i pass a JSON or XML in the request body if i use this approach ?

Comment: @AnandDivakaran If you need the full code for a post request, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6158966/477878) shows how to do that. In this case, you'll only need to replace `http` with `https` and add the key and cert options shown above to the `post_options` for client certificates to work.

Comment: Isn't there a library which handles client-side certificates? I was using [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) but ran into this need and it doesn't seem to support that.