# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED at exports._errnoException at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, handshake, starttls

I am trying to download a file using a url link but I am getting following error

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>      at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)

I have used wget url but I am getting below

> failed: Connection refused

it was said that for https we need a server certificate  and show it when we authenticate it but how to show certificate and get the file

i have used wireshark and saw that there is some problem with ssl handshake
 so i have downloaded the certificate of the server so what should i do  now

My Nodejs code

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.xlsx");
var request = https.get("https://example.com/secure/attachment/206906/a-373_update.xlsx", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Comment: You use the `http` module for making HTTPS requests (you need to use the [`https` module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) instead), which will throw an error (although a different one from what you're showing).

Comment: @robertklep it is showing same error even i have used the https module i have edited my post please see

Comment: I assume that the URL is actually valid? Did you try retrieving it using something like cURL?

Comment: i am able to download the file manually by pasting it in browser the url above is an example not an exat

Comment: And you're not using a proxy or something?

Comment: no i am not using proxy there is some error with ssl handshake as seen in wireshark

Comment: If your server requires a client certificate, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23578373/893780).

Comment: how to get client key and client.crt

Comment: That's something that the server owner should provide (_if_ that's the reason for your problems).

Comment: cant we create client key and .crt using site/server certificate

Comment: I don't think so, but it using client side certificates doesn't make sense in your use case (for instance, the server owner never mentions them), it may not be the cause of your problems.

Comment: when i am using wget url i am getting failed: Connection refused

Comment: what should i do now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - [How to track down error in node network code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241944/how-to-track-down-error-in-node-network-code/54260655) - while I doubt the details of your issue are the same as mine, it's likely that using the NODE_DEBUG environmental variable would help in your case also.