# how to make a POST request using request.js that includes options

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, httprequest

I'm sure that this is a basic syntax question, but I am trying to hit [an API](https://www.rezdy.com/api/agent-api-getting-started/) that wants "a request" structured like:

```
{"customer":{"firstName":"Regular","lastName":"Joe"}...}
```

I also want to include some options, including query parameters, i.e.:

```
options = {
    method: "POST"
    url: "https://api.rezdy.com/latest/bookings"
    qs: {
        apiKey: apiKey,
    }
    json: true
}
```

How do I include the former data in the `options` hash so that I can call it like so?

```
request(options, (err, response, body)->
    ...
)
```

I tried doing it with `formData` like so:

```
options = {
    method: "POST"
    url: "https://api.rezdy.com/latest/bookings"
    qs: {
        apiKey: apiKey,
    }
    formData: data
    json: true
}
```

but I am still getting errors back from the API suggesting that it has not received data. What is the correct way to include the data in the options hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official page https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

you can send formdata like this -

```
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })
```

You can also use syntax like jquery - 
For example

```
request({
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: 'xxxxxx',
                        body: data,
                        json: true
                    }, function (error, response, body) {
                        console.log(body);                           
                        };
```

For more info you can read - [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)