# how to post data in node.js with content type ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: node.js, rest, request

I'm having a problem in posting data in node.js with `Content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

```
var loginArgs = {
    data: 'username="xyzzzzz"&"password="abc12345#"',

    //data: {
    //    'username': "xyzzzzz",
    //    'password': "abc12345#",
    //},

    headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'MYAPI',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'      
    }   
};
```

And post request is:

```
client.post("http:/url/rest/login", loginArgs, function(data, response){
console.log(loginArgs);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log('succesfully logged in, session:', data.msg);
}
```

It always returns **username/password** incorrect.

In the rest api it is said that the request body should be:

```
username='provide user name in url encoded
format'&password= "provide password in url encoded format'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`request` supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` form uploads. For `multipart/related` refer to the multipart API.

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded (URL-Encoded Forms)**

URL-encoded forms are simple:

```
const request = require('request');

request.post('http:/url/rest/login', {
  form: {
    username: 'xyzzzzz',
    password: 'abc12345#'
  }
})
// or
request.post('http:/url/rest/login').form({
  username: 'xyzzzzz',
  password: 'abc12345#'
})
// or
request.post({
  url: 'http:/url/rest/login',
  form: {
    username: 'xyzzzzz',
    password: 'abc12345#'
  }
}, function (err, httpResponse, body) { /* ... */ })
```

See: https://github.com/request/request#forms

Or, using `request-promise`

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
rp.post('http:/url/rest/login', {
  form: {
    username: 'xyzzzzz',
    password: 'abc12345#'
  }
}).then(...);
```

See: https://github.com/request/request-promise#api-in-detail

Comment: This comment is no longer applicable. The `request` module is marked as deprecated. https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 16):

application/x-www-form-urlencoded requires that you URL encode your Key and Values ([MSDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)).
For illustration:

```
data:`${encodeURI('username')}=${encodeURI('xyzzzzz')}&${encodeURI('password')}=${encodeURI('abc12345')}`
```

**Request Library has been deprecated**, as commented by @Bram.

The example I will write will use the standard HTTPS library which comes with NodeJS.
You could write it as the following (in typescript):

```
import * as https from 'https';
// import * as http from 'http'; // For HTTP instead of HTTPS

export class ApiExample {

    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-empty
    constructor() { }

    public async postLogin(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        // application/x-www-form-urlencoded requires the syntax "UrlEncodedKey=UrlEncodedValue&UrlEncodedKey2=UrlEncodedValue2"
        const xFormBody = `${encodeURI('username')}=${encodeURI(username)}&${encodeURI('password')}=${encodeURI(password)}`;

        return this.performRequest(xFormBody)
    }

    private performRequest(requestBody: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            const options: https.RequestOptions = {
                hostname: 'example.url.com',
                port: 443,
                path: '/login',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(requestBody)
                }
            };

            // const req = http.request(options, function (res) { // For HTTP
            const req = https.request(options, function (res) {
                // This may need to be modified based on your server's response.
                res.setEncoding('utf8');

                let responseBody = '';

                // Build JSON string from response chunks.
                res.on('data', (chunk) => responseBody = responseBody + chunk);
                res.on('end', function () {
                    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(responseBody + '');

                    // Resolve or reject based on status code.
                    res.statusCode !== 200 ? reject(parsedBody) : resolve(parsedBody);
                });
            });

            // Make sure to write the request body.
            req.write(requestBody);
            req.end();
            req.on('error', function (e) { reject(e); });
        });
    }
}

export default ApiExample;
```

Comment: NOTE: encodeURI will unfortunetally give bad results in regards to how it encodes spaces. Form bodies are supposed to be encoded with an older version of the percent-encoding standard, which encodes spaces as "+" instead of "%20", among other things. The newer [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) class will accurately encode the data. See [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) to learn more.

Comment: I had to use encodeURIComponent (instead of encodeURI) when building the request body

Answer (score 7):

Use node's URLSearchParams class to encode the js object to "url encoded" form and pass the string as the request body.
[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams)

Comment: A code example might explain this a bit clearer:

```
const a = new URLSearchParams();
a.append('test', 'value');
a.append('test2', 'value2');
console.log(a.toString()); // will log 'test=value&test2=value2'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using axios package, Here is the solution.

If you have the headers as `Content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

then you will call post API as

```
const response: any = await axios.post(URL, bodyData,  {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
```

URL is you API url like http//YOUR_HOST/XYZ..., and

bodyData is the data which you want to send in post API,

Now how will you pass it ?

Suppose you have data as object, so you have to encode it as url, let me show you

```
let data = {
username: name,
password: password
}
```

then your bodyData will be like

`` let bodyData = `username=${name}&password=${password}` ``

This is the way you can pass your data in body if header is
`Content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

If you have a huge data which you cannot encode it manually then you can use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) module

run command `npm i qs` and in your file

```
const qs = require('qs');

...

let data = {
username: name,
password: password,
manyMoreKeys: manyMoreValues
} 
 
let bodyData = qs.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the [got package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) has built-in functionality that works:

```
const got = require('got');

const response = await got.post(url, {form: {a: 'd', b: 'b', c: 'c'});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [got package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)

```js
const got = require('got');
const qs = require('qs');

const body = qs.stringify({
    a: 'd',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c',
});
```

In async function

```js
const response = await got.post(url, { body });
```

> If the Content-Type header is not present, it will be set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

use Node's [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) library to encode data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format before passing it as the body to your REST request.

I'm not sure what library you are using (jQuery?) but it looks like you should be able to call it like this:

```
const querystring = require('node:querystring'); 
const loginArgs = {
  data: querystring.stringify({
    'username': "xyzzzzz",
    'password': "abc12345#",
  }),
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'MYAPI',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'      
  }
};
client.post(
  "http:/url/rest/login",
  loginArgs,
  function(data, response) {
    console.log(loginArgs);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('succesfully logged in, session:', data.msg);
    }
  }
}
```

assuming that this `client.post` takes an object as it's 2nd argument where the `data` property is a string to use as the REST body.