# Node JS : How to make a POST call using header, input body JSON to an URL

Tags: node.js, post

I have an URL to which i need to make an POST Call, given that i have Header Value, Request Body in JSON and the URl to make an POST Call.

```
Header      : {
                Authorization: "some_authorization_key",
                Content-Type: "application/json"
              }
URL         : http://someurl.com/somepath
input JSON  : {
                key : sdasddasdas,
                name: name
              }
request Method : POST
```

I need to POST call in node js using the above details.

Can anyone provide me the code how to make an POST call using the above details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You may code like this using require library.

```
var request = require('request');  
    request.post(
        'http://www.nameofsite.com/yourpage',
        { form: { key: 'value' } },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: but i need to POST it with using the HEADER keys and the input JSON value. how can i post using header and input JSON value

Comment: request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
}, ...