# Converting Unix command into Windows command

Tags: node.js, windows, unix

I have to work on Windows, However I have some difficulties to convert a UNIX command into a Windows command.

I have a node.js server which execute this command :

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
...
...
let output = execSync('output=$(wget --post-data '
+ '"' + text + '" ' + '"localhost:' + port
+ '/?properties={"annotators": ' + '"' + annotators + '", "outputFormat": "'
+ format + '"' + "}' -qO -) && echo $output', { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Why don't you [do it with node](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6158933/7552) instead of calling out to an external command?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is the bash syntax, you need to convert the things into windows cmd line format.

- wget is not available by default on windows commmand line. See this:
  [Wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Comment: @onedkr by default there is no native command like wget in Windows. You can check that link for a windows version of Wget

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to run UNIX commands on Windows. You can download all of the UNIX commands compiled for Windows from this GitHub repository: https://github.com/George-Ogden/UNIX