# How do I make a https post in Node Js without any third party module?

Tags: node.js, post, https

I'm working on a project that requires https get and post methods. I've got a short https.get function working here...

```
const https = require("https");

function get(url, callback) {
    "use-strict";
    https.get(url, function (result) {
        var dataQueue = "";    
        result.on("data", function (dataBuffer) {
            dataQueue += dataBuffer;
        });
        result.on("end", function () {
            callback(dataQueue);
        });
    });
}

get("https://example.com/method", function (data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

My problem is that there's no https.post and I've already tried the http solution here with https module [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js) but returns console errors.

I've had no problem using get and post with Ajax in my browser to the same api. I can use https.get to send query information but I don't think this would be the correct way and I don't think it will work sending files later if I decide to expand.

Is there a small example, with the minimum requirements, to make a https.request what would be a https.post if there was one? I don't want to use npm modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)

Comment: @congusbongus: not exactly because this question is about HTTPS, different from HTTP...

Comment: ten years later, **node-fetch** is here now, it's trivial

Answer (score 251, accepted):

For example, like this:

```
const https = require('https');

var postData = JSON.stringify({
    'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
  hostname: 'posttestserver.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/post.php',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Content-Length': postData.length
     }
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Comment: Nice answer @aring. If you want to send JSON, change the following:
```var postData = JSON.stringify({msg: 'Hello World!'})```
and
```'Content-Type': 'application/json'```

Comment: Thanks - I found out the hard way that using require('http') and setting port to 443 in options was not the right way to send a HTTP request.

Comment: I am assuming that `req.write(postData);` would be the posting of the data, would I be correct? I have data coming back from where I posted to, and get outputed data in JSON in the terminal. How would I be able to save that data to a variable from which I got back?

Comment: Might want to check to see if res.statusCode is 200 and if not, take error action.

Comment: Given that querystring is nowadays considered legacy code you might want to replace it with URLSearchParams https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams

Answer (score 50):

Here's a version slightly different from the accepted answer:

- @returns `Promise`
- You can pass the URL directly (no need to split to hostname, path, port)
- It handles error HTTP status codes
- It handles connection timeouts
- For an alternative content type example, it sends JSON instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```js
const https = require('https')

function post(url, data) {
  const dataString = JSON.stringify(data)

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': dataString.length,
    },
    timeout: 1000, // in ms
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
        return reject(new Error(`HTTP status code ${res.statusCode}`))
      }

      const body = []
      res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', () => {
        const resString = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
        resolve(resString)
      })
    })

    req.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err)
    })

    req.on('timeout', () => {
      req.destroy()
      reject(new Error('Request time out'))
    })

    req.write(dataString)
    req.end()
  })
}

const res = await post('https://...', data)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Max. Why JSON.stringify instead of querystring.stringify?

Comment: @Guido in this example we're `POST`ing `application/json`.

Comment: If you know the approximate size of the data being received pre-allocating body (or a Buffer for it) would be good.

Comment: How does wrapping the code with `new Promise()` add anything?

Comment: the res.statusCode check should happen within the res.on('end'), because we may get an error status code, but we might as well get an explanatory body containing the reason.

Comment: FYI, If you get a timeout, you might have forgot the req.end() which is automatically done for the get function.

Comment: This helped me tremendously with how to properly return the entire response body. Thanks!!

Answer (score 21):

## In Node.js 18 and above

Say goodbye to the **node-fetch package** ,**axios** and **request** ,**...** now the **fetch** API is available on the global scope by default.

**POST REQUEST**

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    // Make a post Request.
    
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: 'foo',
            body: 'bar',
            userId: 1,
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })

    res.send('Fetch API is available on the global scope by default')
})
```

**GET REQUEST**

```
const res = await fetch('https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.json');
if (res.ok) {
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

We can make requests as we do in browsers.

**[For More Information](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental)**

Comment: OP said, _"My problem is that there's no https.post"_. So does the fetch API support POST as well?

Comment: @xpt, You can call all the HTTP verbs such as POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, and GET. I tried the POST method It works.

Comment: Oh, good to know, Would you post your testing POST method here please, as the question OP has is _"How do I make a https post in Node Js"_ whereas your answer above is HTTP GET only.

Answer (score 5):

## With Node.js 18 and above, "fetch" is standard.

## Node 16 just reached its end-of-life, so everything

## else is ancient history

```
console.log("trying ...")

let body = {
    "ids": ["4e4e4e4e-4e4e-4e4e-4e4e-4e4e4e4e4e4e"]
};

fetch('https://blahblah.com/blah', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': 'superamazingsecretcryptostuff',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // fyi, NO need for content length
    }
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch (err => console.log(err))

console.log("done....")
```

Job done.

Comment: Isn't the question specifically about doing this *without any 3rd party module* though?

Comment: @ibz it's not third party, it's built right in - that's the big news.  at last

Comment: I added const `fetch = require('node-fetch');` to the top of my lambda function but caught `Cannot find module 'node-fetch'` ? Any ideas why?

Comment: @Fattie Sorry, my bad. Seems indeed it has been finally merged into Node! I didn't know, and your note `// note: use npm install` made me think you are trying to use it as an external package. Great news! PS: I would now upvote but SO won't let me unless you edit your answer. Perhaps just edit and add a comment saying `// included as of node v17.5.0` just to be clear for all?

Comment: i only realized it thanks to SO !

Comment: I assume this code is compatible with the browser-based "fetch", right? So essentially the same code will be able to be used in node.js and in the browser to make an external request, which is pretty neat!

Comment: @ibz unfortunately I know almost nothing about browser tech.  (We do apps and servers! :) )  So I leave that to others.  ("Does this have to do with html?!"  :) )

Comment: Edited the answer to omit the "require" that is unnecessary now that node 18 is the minimum supported version.

Comment: @Fattie - You can not simply add another answer in your answer without specifying his/her name.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537749/how-do-i-make-a-https-post-in-node-js-without-any-third-party-module/71991926#71991926