# How to access post object from http request using nodejs

Tags: node.js, object, https

The simple version of my question is: How can I get access to the hello world part of this object:
`{ '{"msg":"Hello World!"}': '' }`

The longer and introductionary version is; I've been trying to send and receive postBody objects, but I can't seem to access the data from the request i've sent.

I think I'm missing something simple, I recreated a request from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537749/how-do-i-make-a-https-post-in-node-js-without-any-third-party-module), but I can't seem to access the "hello world" part of the body.

An answer as to how to access the inner object, and optional tips and/or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Post request:

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({ msg: "Hello World!" });
  var options = {
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 5000,
    path: "/tester",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "Content-Length": postData.length,
    },
  };
  var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log("statusCode:", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers:", res.headers);
    res.on("data", (d) => {
      // console.log("d", d)
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });
  req.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
```

Receive request:

```
app.get("/tester", (req, res) => {
  console.log("request fired");
  console.log("body:", req.body);
  let x = req.body
  console.log(typeof x);
  res.end();
});
```

log:

```
request fired
body: { '{"msg":"Hello World!"}': '' }
object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `JSON.stringify` when you are sending the data. So when you receive it just parse it using `JSON.parse`. Something like this

```
let data = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

Now you can access `msg` from your body like this

```
console.log(data.msg);
```

This will return `Hello World!`

Your case seems to be weird in your case for some reason your data is in the key of the object you can access data like this

```
let data = {'{"msg":"Hello World!"}': ''}

console.log(JSON.parse(Object.keys(data)[0]).msg)
```

```js
let stringifiedData = JSON.stringify({
  msg: "Hello World!"
});

console.log(stringifiedData);

let parsedData = JSON.parse(stringifiedData);

console.log(parsedData.msg);

/* UPDATE */

let data = {
  '{"msg":"Hello World!"}': ''
}

console.log(JSON.parse(Object.keys(data)[0]).msg)
```

Comment: I've tried this and got error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1", after some research it found JSON.parse can't parse objects. Therefore I think I need to lose the brackets first, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @DuncanKooyman Check the update

Comment: Of course, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!