# Establishing communication between two different server i.e. WebSphere and Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, websphere

I have 1.WebSphere web app and 2.Node.js web app, both are running independently. Currently WebSphere app is able to speak to Node.js app via HTTP/HTTPS. Now I have reached to the point where I want to inform the WebSphere app for certain changes from Node.js app. I know about socket.io but it will work within the application. Is there any solution like `socket.emit` from Node.js and `socket.on` in WebSphere app?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood why `socket.io` is not a viable solution. Can you explain in more detail what do you want to do and why socket.io does not work for you?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas I didn't tried socket.io for two different servers, I have tried within nodejs

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to send data from nodejs server to websphere server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)

Comment: Please check the page above - I think making an HTTP post request may achieve what you want to do.

Comment: ok thanks @DeividasKaržinauskas