# Node HTTPS Request – MalformedJsonException

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a POST request using node/HTTPS, but I keep getting this error:

> BODY: {"message":"MalformedJsonException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   11 path $","mdcKey":""}

Here's the code that initiates the request:

```
  const https = require('https');

  const querystring = require('querystring');

  const POSTData = querystring.stringify({
    'addressTo': 'myemail@address.com',
    'subject': 'testing your email template',
    'templateName': 'genericTemplate',
    'bodyText': 'this is a test'
  });

  console.log(POSTData);

  const HTTPOptions = {
    hostname: 'url.com',
    port: 00000,
    path: '/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  const HTTPSrequest = https.request(HTTPOptions, (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
  });

  HTTPSrequest.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${error}`);
  });

  // write data to request body
  HTTPSrequest.write(POSTData);
  HTTPSrequest.end();
```

I'm assuming it's the POSTData that is the "malformed JSON", here's what it looks like stringified:

> addressTo=name%40companyname.com&subject=testing%20your%20email%20template&templateName=genericTemplate&bodyText=this%20is%20a%20test

I'm not sure what I'm doing that is causing the malformed JSON. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload but telling the server it's `application/json`. The server is complaining because of this mismatch.

The simple solution should be to just change `querystring.stringify` to `JSON.stringify`.

You may also need to specify a `Content-Length` header since some servers may not support chunked requests (which is the default in node). If you do add this, make sure you use `Buffer.byteLength(POSTData)` as the header value instead of just `POSTData.length` since the former works for multi-byte characters and the latter returns the number of characters (not bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Help more with explication from @mscdex

Your options object after `querystring.stringify` has returned. Otherwise you won't know the `length` of the stringified body data.

It is important to note that you need two extra headers in your options object in order to make a successful post request. These are :

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Content-Length': POSTData.length
```

Check example:

```
  const HTTPOptions = {
    hostname: 'url.com',
    port: 00000,
    path: '/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',          
      'Content-Length': POSTData.length
    }
  };
```

You can see this examples too: [1st post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js).

Answer (score -1):

JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 11 path $","mdcKey":""}

Comment: I don't think this gets to the root of the issue. Why was the JSON malformed to begin with?

Comment: Can you be more clear what you suggested solution is?