# data exchange via localhost in node.js

Tags: node.js, data-exchange

in the following code, app1.js sends information on localhost port 3000

```
    //app1.js 
    var http = require('http');
    const valueToTransfert = 'test';
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.end('valueToTransfert');
    });
    server.listen(3000);
```

I want to make a second program app2.js that will run simultaneously and read data sent by app1.js on localhost:3000.

How can I do that ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Create another server to receive your request and take a look at [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999483/8298495)

Comment: It is necessary to make another server ? There is no way to "listen" a port and collect the information ?

Comment: Ah, perhaps you could use a child_process and call it directly, I haven't tried that, but it might be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but it might work your your immediate purposes

```
require('child_process').exec('node app2.js test', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    // you get your results in stdout
    // app2.js would have to output its result with console.log(...);
});
```

But if you need to send more data you will probably have to setup another server, or do something a bit more complex.