# How to send formdata in a http request from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to upload a file in a https request using form data. I have this

```
function uploadDocument(filepath) {
    var options = {
        host : 'myserver',
        port : 443,
        path : '/platform-api/v1/documents',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer 56356363',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
        }
    };
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        var buffer = "";
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            buffer += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(chunk) {
            var json = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
            console.log(json);
        });
    });

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filepath));
    form.append('project_id', 4);
    form.pipe(req);

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request:', e.message);
    });
    req.end();
}
```

but I get back

```
problem with request: write after end
{ errors:
   { file: 'missing-required-key',
     project_id: 'missing-required-key' } }
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js

Comment: How can I wait for the pipe to finish like asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479347/how-to-wait-for-the-pipe-to-finish-in-form-data-node-js-module

Comment: try removing `req.end()` the documentation seems to be saying that it works without it

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `req.end()` when `pipe` already called.

FormData is asynchronous stream and you can't call `req.end()` right after calling `.pipe(req)`. According to [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options), pipe by default calls `end()` for the writer stream (`req` in this case) when reader stream (form itself) ends.

So use `req.end()` when you don't need `pipe`, and don't use `req.end()` if you used pipe.