# How to wait for the pipe to finish in form-data node.js module?

Tags: node.js, request, form-data

Using the form-data module in node.js, you can do this

```
form.pipe(request)
```

to put the form data to the request. But how can you wait until it is complete? Is there a callback like this

```
form.pipe(request).done(function(err) {});
```

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the docs, they use:

```
form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to get my tests to work:

```
app.js

// form is declared

return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(
         process.env.HOST,
         {
           method: 'POST',
           headers: form.getHeaders()
         },
         (res) => {
           let data = '';

           res.on('data', (d) => {
             data += d;
           });

           res.on('end', () => {
             resolve({
               statusCode: res.statusCode,
               body: data,
             });
          });
        },
    ).on('error', reject);

    form.pipe(req);
});
```

and

```
test-handler.js

sinon.replace(https, 'request', (url, options, callback) => {
  const request = new EventEmitter();

  request.on('pipe', () => {
    const res = new EventEmitter();

    res.statusCode = 200;

    callback(res);

    res.emit(
        'data',
        JSON.stringify({}),
    );
    res.emit('end');
  });

  return request;
});
```

I understand that it doesn't strictly answer your question in that the "pipe" event fires when the pipe begins and not when it's complete, but in terms of testing I don't know how to otherwise make the response finish.