# How to pass post data in http request method

Tags: json, node.js, http, post

The following error prompts when my code executes.
It seems that `body`parameter could not be read.

> missing required input JSON parameter requestType.

```
app.post('/compare', function (req, res, next) {
    var options = {
        host: 'hostname',
        port: 80,
        path: '/service',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + pass).toString("base64")
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          requestType: 'createService'
        })
      };
   var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
     response.on('data', function (chunk) {
       console.log("body: " + chunk);
     });
    response.on('end', function() {
      res.send('ok');
    })
   });
   httpreq.end();
});
```

Comment: can add the complete code?

Comment: remove JSON.stringify from body.

Comment: that didn't help

Comment: refer this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked node's http modules latest [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) for `request` method.

It's options parameter does not accepts any `body` attribute

There is a example as well which shows that you need to pass `body` in write method

```
const postData = JSON.stringify({
      requestType: 'createService'
    });

const options = var options = {
    host: 'hostname',
    port: 80,
    path: '/service',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + pass).toString("base64")
    }
  };

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```