# Upload file to s3 from protractor E2E test

Tags: curl, protractor

I am need to upload file to S3 using CURL via POST in my protractor E2E test
I would like to understand if it is possible to do it that way .

Comment: [AWS SDK for Node](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), [How to make a POST request in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js).  Also what have you tried?

Comment: this is great. I have tried using "request" package. Wasn't successful though

Comment: @Ninja have you found a solution?