# Extracting a variable from an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code, take from this example: [How is an HTTP POST request made in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://www.yoursite.com/formpage',
    { json: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
    }
);
```

How do I make the variable **body** known globally in the program and not only in the anonymous function?

The problem I face is that my function is surrounded by a function which has to return the value of what is queried in the request of the url.

Comment: The function is **asynchronous** so making the variable global won't really do you any good. What you need to do is place the "work" necessary *inside* the callback function.

Comment: Is it not possible to wait until it is finished and then make it known globally or it is the wrong way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Generally there's no "waiting" in JavaScript. There are facilities to make code *appear* to wait — `async` functions and the `await` expression — but those work with Promise objects and everything is still asynchronous.