# How do I send a request from One Nodejs application to another using an IP address?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 Nodejs Server running. One of the server just has a post route:

```
app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(`Someone sent a post request`)
})
```

This server is running on `localhost:9000`. How do I fire the post route from a different Nodejs Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something similar to this:

```
var request = require("request");

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/employee',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: { id: 1 },
        json: true
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log(body);
        // Process the body and return the response.
        return res.send(body);
    });
});
```

Additional [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)

Comment: This works but can I use an IP address instead of localhost. For example going to route like 123.123.123:9000 ?

Comment: Yes. You can. But just make sure port `9000` has access (firewall settings) from where you are accessing.