# What's "form.getHeaders();?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post, request

I mean, i'm trying to make the most simple upload ever, with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');

var request = http.request({
  method: 'post',
  host: 'https://www.ws-ti.4bank.com',
  path: '/img/create_file',
  headers: form.getHeaders()
});

form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {

  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

The point is, if i make a post like this, what it'll post exacly?
Does i need to put at least one header parameter or this create some kind of template?
If i need to put at least one parameter, i would put it into the form.getHeaders"()"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is an HTTP POST request made in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)

Comment: There is a whole mess of request options you must set to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `headers` you should send HTTP headers of the request as an object

Example code:

```
var request = http.request({
  method: 'post',
  host: 'https://www.ws-ti.4bank.com',
  path: '/img/create_file',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'text/html',
  }
});
```

full list of the header can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

You can send data as JSON with the request as follows:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
  text: 'Hello World'
});

request.write(data);
request.end();
```

Comment: ok, and how can i send a simple "Hello World" as the body of my POST request?

Comment: if it solves your issue please mark the answer as correct which can help other people as well 

Comment: ops sry, i forgot

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "what does form.getHeaders() actually return.