# How to post data in node.js with content type ='application/x-protobuf'

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm having problem in post data with content-type='application/x-protobuf'. Can we request protobuf from HTTP request? if can how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

It is going to be just another regular request if you encode and decode protobuffer.

The best option is to use a library such as [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) for encoding and decoding.

Here is a simple axios request with proto buffer.

```
  const protobuf = require('protobufjs');

  ...

  const root = await protobuf.load('user.proto');  
  const User = root.lookupType('userpackage.User');

  const postBody = User.encode({ name: 'Joe', age: 27 }).finish();

  await axios.post('http://someaddress', postBody,  {
           headers: {
           'content-type': 'application/x-protobuf'
  }}).
  then(res => res.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`content-type` is usually passed as a header.

You could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158966/5497658) for a hint on how to pass headers on a POST request.